# HTML5 games for OUYA?

Tags: html5, ouya

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but since [OUYA](http://www.ouya.tv/) is shipping with android 4.0 I'll try.

Anyway, for those of you who are familiar with the platform I'm wondering if it will be possible to launch HTML5/Javascript games wrapped in app for OUYA?

Comment: This will be the right place for OUYA questions, but since it hasn't launched yet any answers are going to be speculative at best, and thus not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Speculation: If it has webkit and v8, and your game would run ok on other devices than yes, it should run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works.

[Game Closure](http://www.gameclosure.com/) (which is HTML/Javascript) runs on OUYA. There are some posts by staff members on the mailing list. It takes some work to get controller support as of writing (they're working on making it available out of the box).